# How to set up conditionals in Google OR-Tools?

Tags: python, or-tools

I’m trying to use OR-Tools to solve  custom nurse scheduling problem - essentially each nurse works exactly two paired shifts, and gives a ranked list of the paired preferences.

For example, nurse1 has the following preferences:

1. shift 1 and shift 7
2. shift 4 and shift 8
3. shift 2 and shift 6

If the nurse gets assigned to shift 1, he must also work shift 7. If the nurse gets assigned to shift 4, he must also work shift 8. If the nurse gets assigned to shift 2 he must work shift 6.

This holds true for all nurses in the hospital.

I can schedule individual shifts, but I don’t know how to create the requests matrix or link the shifts.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each nurse, I ended up creating a new `BoolVar` for each choice, a `BoolAnd` for each shift pair, and a `BoolOr` for all three shift choices.

```py
first_choice = model.NewBoolVar("first_choice")
second_choice = model.NewBoolVar("second_choice")
third_choice = model.NewBoolVar("third_choice")

model.AddBoolAnd([shifts[(nurse, first_a)], shifts[(nurse, first_b)]]).OnlyEnforceIf(first_choice)
model.AddBoolAnd([shifts[(nurse, second_a)], shifts[(nurse, secon_b_b)]]).OnlyEnforceIf(second_choice)
model.AddBoolAnd([shifts[(nurse, third_a)], shifts[(nurse, third_b)]]).OnlyEnforceIf(third_choice)

model.AddBoolOr([first_choice, second_choice, third_choice])
```

This seems to have done the job.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is just use the same Boolean variables for the 2 shifts.

Now, if you want to implement the following constraint

```
b1 <=> b2 && b3
```

I suggest reading the following [recipe](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/boolean_logic.md#product-of-two-boolean-variables). Note that it can be expanded to more than 2 variables in the conjunction.

Comment: If I do that, will partial overlaps be possible? Meaning if I want to have a two nurses per shift, can one nurse be assigned shift 1 and shift 7, and the other shift 7 and shift 8?

Comment: Also, wouldn’t I need to set up a separate Boolean variable for each possible shift combination?

Comment: Yes, , you will need 1 BoolVar per combination. Just try to reuse/cache them as much as possible.